# Using xmlhttp to load multifile from server

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I use xmlhttp to load text file from server. I can only load 1 file, how can I load multifile? here is the code :

```
      function load_controll_unit_enable_disable_default()
      {
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var arr = [];
                arr = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");
            }                   
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","file.txt",true);

        xmlhttp.send();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is limited to receiving only one response per one request. If you want to get more in one swoop try serializing using JSON. For example request `/files` which returns a JSON array:

```
[ { 'file': 'file.txt', 'data': ... }, { 'file': '...', 'data': ... }, ... ]
```

`JSON.parse` it and read each filedata. Note that JSON does not support binary data, only UTF-8, so for binary you'll probably have to armor it (base64 `btoa` and `atob`, etc.).